# Jquery get ID of element within containing Div

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have some buttons inside a div like so:

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button id="addRed" class="addTriangle">Add red</button>
    <button id="addGreen" class="addTriangle">Add green</button>
    <button id="addBlue" class="addTriangle">Add blue</button>
    <button id="addPurple" class="addTriangle">Add purple</button>
</div><!--buttons-->
```

and rather than write a handler for each button, I want to just write one function that creates a new element based on its ID.

If I use this:

```
$("#buttons").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id);
});
```

I get the id of the parent, but how do I get the id of the particular button that was clicked?

Comment: $(".addTriangle")...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the click event handler to actual buttons like:

```
$("#buttons > button").click(function(){
     alert(this.id);
});
```

or using the class name like:

```
$(".addTriangle").click(function(){
     alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the class click event

```js
$(".addTriangle").click(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(id);
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
    <button id="addRed" class="addTriangle">Add red</button>
    <button id="addGreen" class="addTriangle">Add green</button>
    <button id="addBlue" class="addTriangle">Add blue</button>
    <button id="addPurple" class="addTriangle">Add purple</button>
</div><!--buttons-->
```